# Codeigniter MVC practice

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I'm finding that I need to write a lot of duplicate code given that I'm unable to call functions from other controllers. For example, here the news feed stuff is repeated throughout my code where I do something specific to one controller then need to load my news feed like so. Is this typical of MVC, am I missing some codeigniter tool, or am I just doing it wrong?

```
function register_user() {

    //registration stuff
    $userName = $this->input->post('username');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $data = array(
        'name' => $userName,
        'email' => $email
    );

    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->user_model->register_user($data);

    //news feed stuff
    $this->load->model('NewsFeed_model');
    $data['queryMovies'] = $this->NewsFeed_model->getPublications();        
    $this->load->view('news_feed_view', $data);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either [create a library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) or a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) that you can call from all your controllers or you can create a common controller base class (my personal favorite) with the common functions and have all your CI controllers inherit from it.